# When I run the code, get the results and repeat, the previous user input displays right before the new user input. Any idea?

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone help steer me into the right direction?
I am trying to separate the string into characters. If the character is lowercase then the program will uppercase it and vice versa.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim Input As String
        Dim Output As New Text.StringBuilder()
        Dim repeat As String = "Y"

        Do While repeat = "Y"
            Console.Clear()

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a word or" &
            "phrase and I will change upper case to lower case and vice versa")
            Input = Console.ReadLine

            For Each ch As Char In Input

                If Char.IsLower(ch) Then
                    Output.Append(Char.ToUpper(ch))
                ElseIf Char.IsUpper(ch) Then
                    Output.Append(Char.ToLower(ch))
                Else
                    Output.Append(ch)
                End If

            Next

            Console.WriteLine(Output.ToString())    
            Console.Write("Lets try another (Y/N) ")    
            repeat = UCase(Console.ReadLine())    
        Loop

        Console.ReadKey()    
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You need to debug your code, i.e. set a breakpoint, step through it line by line and examine the state.  That's how you diagnose bugs.  Not simply by reading the code.  You need to do that before posting here and, if you still can't work out what to do, provide us with all the information you gathered while debugging.

Comment: Also, do everything you can to help us help you, which includes not including huge wads of empty space ion your code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I've been beating myself up about this code for days.I tried everything and sorry about the format. I am new to this site and programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what you're doing with `Output`; you keep appending to it, but never remove the results from the previous loop from it, so it's gonna display it again and again.

So to fix your problem you need to make sure `output` is emptied before adding new characters to it. I don't really work with stringbuilders but a simple way would be to just do

`Output = New Text.StringBuilder()`

at the beginning of your loop

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thank you so much! You have been super helpful.